# Form to delete selected row in database: displays confirmation always

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, sql-delete

I have a form to delete a row from my sql database.  I had it functioning yesterday but for some reason it won't successfully delete anything, just comes back with a confirmation message.  I know all of my login/connection details are correct.  Please tell me if there is some error in this script.

PHP

```
if(isset($_POST['delete']))
{
$dbhost = '';
$dbuser = '';
$dbpass = '';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $conn )
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
$address = $_POST['address'];

$sql = "DELETE FROM units WHERE address = '$address'";

mysql_select_db('db_units');
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
die('Could not delete data: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "Deleted data successfully\n";
mysql_close($conn);
}
else
{
```

Form

```
<form method="post" action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>">

<td><input name="address" type="text" address="address"></td>

<input name="delete" type="submit" address="delete" value="Delete">
```

Comment: I don't see anywhere in your PHP where you're setting up the connection to the MySQL database (using the MySQL hostname, username, and password).

Comment: I sincerely hope that's just internal code no one ever gets a chance to do some fine SQL injection to.

Comment: Yeah, if someone enters `'; DELETE FROM units WHERE 1 or address = '` in the address field, that's the end of the records in the units table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All functions in PHP prefixed `mysql_` are deprecated. Using the functions prefixed with `mysqli_` or the OOP version is recommended. Here is code that I'm sure would work, I don't have the privilege of testing right now because I'm on my phone. I personally use the object-oriented version of `mysqli`, but this is mostly up to you.

```
<?php

$link = new mysqli( $host, $user, $password, $database );

if ( isset( $_POST['delete'] ) ) {

    $address = $_POST['address'];

    $sql = "DELETE FROM `units` WHERE `address` = '{$address}'";

    if ( ! $retval = $link->query( $sql ) )
        die( "Could not delete data: " . $link->error );

}

?>
```

This is obviously just internal code and for simplicity I didn't sanitize/validate anything. However, **proper sanitation & validation is a must**.
[You can learn more about mysqli here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

Comment: Thanks so much for that but I am still unable to get it to function correctly.  I have no experience in SQL and while I'm interested to learn it... I don't have the time in this project!  I'll give it another shot tomorrow.

Comment: Now's your chance to learn MySQL (: [Here is a great reference](http://www.pantz.org/software/mysql/mysqlcommands.html) of MySQL commands that helped me a lot as a beginner.

Comment: I got it!  The space between the '=' and $address should not have been there and now it's functional.